Able to read from google sheet but unable to write to google sheet using Javascript
I'm able to read rows from my google sheet, but unable to write to it (append rows)..
That probably means that I'm clear on the whole authentication business right?
Below is my code for trying to write to the first two cells of my sheet. I don't get any error message, I get a message that data has been successfully sent to the sheet, but I don't see anything updated on my sheet
    const url = `https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/${sheetId}/values/${sheetName}!A1:B1:append?valueInputOption=USER_ENTERED`; 
    chrome.identity.getAuthToken({ interactive: true }, function (token) {
      console.log(token);

      fetch(url, {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          values: [[1, 2]],
          range: "Sheet1!A1:B1",
          majorDimension: "ROWS",
        }),
      })
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((data) => sendResponse({ data }))
        .catch((error) => sendResponse({ error: error.message }));
    });

Below is my code for reading from the sheet. This works!
    const url = `https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/${sheetId}/values/${sheetName}?key=${apiKey}`;
    chrome.identity.getAuthToken({ interactive: true }, function (token) {
      console.log(token);

     fetch(url)
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((data) => sendResponse({ data }))
        .catch((error) => sendResponse({ error: error.message }));
    });

In my manifest.json, I have as follows
 "oauth2": {
    "client_id": "<CLIENT ID>.apps.googleusercontent.com",
    "scopes": ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets"]
  }

I get past the authorization/consent screen and any credential confirming steps, but I just don't see anything updated on the actual sheet when I'm trying to write!
I tried changing the access level of the google sheet itself from Restricted to Anyone with link. For reading, setting the level to Anyone with link worked. For writing, neither of them worked.
I enabled viewing of protected range in the google sheet. Still nothing was written.

That probably means that I'm clear on the whole authentication business right? Not necessarily. To be honest, it's not at all clear what you are trying to do, and what outcome you are getting. I suggest that you read How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example; then edit the question to describe your scenario, describe the actual problem that you are having, include sample data and provide an example of a successful outcome.

Your HTTPS request for appending to the sheet is incorrect.
The second argument passed to  fetch is a RequestInit object which has no range or majorDimension properties.
Here is the API documentation for appending to a sheet and this is how the request's body should look like

I actually solved the issue. I forgot to enable Google Spreadsheet API in the correct Google Cloud project. With the API enabled, this code does work.

@Titus I think range and majorDimension are part of the acceptable arguments https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/values#javascript_1

@Tedinoz sorry if my question was confusing! I'm trying to write a web app that writes to a google sheet of my choice. That's why I said I have a file called manifest.json etc. Sorry for not making that clear!

I think range and majorDimension are part of the acceptable arguments They are not part of the accepted arguments to fetch, if you want to pass them to the server, you need to include them in the request's body or URL.

@Titus You're totally right! I incorrectly put them outside body. I will modify the code in this question.
